# DirectX11, направленное освещение

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, direct3d

Я использую обычное направленное освещение, по Фонгу, учитывая ambient и diffuse. 
Нормали высчитываются с помощью алгоритма усреднения:
генерируем нормали для каждого треугольника, далее для вершин, которые входят в несколько треугольников, складываем все полученные нормали каждого треугольника, в который входит эта вершина, и усредняем. Пиксельный шейдер прост:

```
cbuffer ConstantBufferPS
{
    float4 Direction; // направление света
    float4 Color; // цвет света
    float4 ambient_factor; // коэффициент фонового освещения
}

struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos: SV_POSITION;
    float3 Normal: TEXCOORD0;
    float4 Color: COLOR0;
};

float4 main(VS_INPUT input): SV_Target
{       
    // ambient освещение
    float4 ambient = (Color * ambient_factor.x) * input.Color;

    // diffuse освещение
    float4 diffuse = saturate(dot(input.Normal, Direction) * Color);

    // устанавливаем прозрачность + итоговый свет
    float4 out_color = (ambient + diffuse) * input.Color;
    out_color.a = 1;

    return out_color;
}
```

Объект не использует текстуру. Однако, при освещении, свет получается не очень мягким:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как просчитать более мягкий свет?
P.S.: я слышал про bump mapping, он придаст рельеф и освещение будет более мягким. Но хотелось бы услышать советы и по моей ситуации, быть может использовать другой алгоритм расчёта нормалей, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой результат типичен при ненормализованных нормалях и векторе освещения.

Нормализуйте `input.Normal` и `Direction`. И `color`, кстати, тоже проверьте, чтобы он был в диапазоне `0..1`. При нормализации учитывайте, что компонент `w` должен быть равен 0, иначе он исказит нормализацию по `xyz`.

Comment: Сделал. Огромное Вам спасибо. Информация о нормализации не была указана в туториалах, всю голову себе сломал. Подскажите, вот, на скриншоте ниже по ссылке, вроде бы уже лучше? Или все равно, некие проблемы остались? Напомню: используются усреднённые нормали(т.е. для этого куба 8 вершин, а не 24, и для каждой нормаль)
http://i-fotki.info/23/c33821cc9633c92252a24c0f07054a586dac37305503374.jpg.html

Comment: @Range Да, на скрине уже почти правильный вариант. Для улучшения, нормаль поверхности надо нормализовывать во фрагментном шейдере (чтобы не было "полигональных градиентов").

Comment: Нормализовал. Либо мне кажется, либо результат не сильно изменился?
http://i-fotki.info/23/a0d4b0cf35342fbd259f86b217c2fe666dac37305504406.jpg.html

Comment: @Range Должен был незначительно улучшится. Это будет больше всего заметно на низкополигональных сферах (около 100 вершин)

Comment: Тогда, получается, закончил. Спасибо огромное! Попробую посадить сверху блики, и модель освещения будет откалибрована:) (для начала)